# What are astrocentric co-ordinates?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, computational-physics

A program I am using requires the ecliptic astrocentric cartesian coordinates of the Earth and the Sun in AU however I have never come across these co-ordinates before and the internet doesn't provide much help
Thanks.

Comment: "Astrocentric" just means centred on a star, so in the Solar System, "astrocentric" is a synonym for "heliocentric". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system#Rectangular_coordinates